# execute js function when a function inside document.ready is done

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a website which computes the performance of each server. One of the requirements is the center partial page which are about performances must be finish loading first before doing another function in the background.

This center partial page uses ajax calls. They are being defined at the `document.ready` of the js file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// ajax call here
// another ajax call here
// third ajax call here
});
```

Then the function that I wanted to execute after the function inside the document ready is done:

```
function functionA() {
// some codes here
});
```

I tried using this:

```
$.when(document).ready(function () {
}).done(functionA);
```

but I can't make it run .. Any suggestions would be gladly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to execute the function when the `document.ready` is done, or when all the AJAX calls complete? Two very different things.

Comment: @RGraham - when the ajax calls are completed.

Answer (score 1):

The first letter in AJAX stands for *asynchronous* which means that at the end of your `document.ready` event, they could be off somewhere else doing some processing. The `document.ready` will not wait for them to finish.

You need to set up jQuery using [.when](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) to tell you when all three AJAX calls are complete:

```
// Document.ready
$(function() {
    // Any synchronous code you may do on DOM ready goes here

    // Set up the promise
    $.when(
        // Pass in all your AJAX calls.
        $.ajax({ url: "/AjaxCall1?param=true" }),
        $.ajax({ url: "/AjaxCall2?param=1" }),
        $.ajax({ url: "/AjaxCall3?param=yup" })
    ).then(function() {
        console.log("All AJAX requests finished");
    }, function() {
        console.log("Something went wrong :(");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to deal with DOM ready event and Ajax calls at the same time :

```
var init, ajax1, ajax2, domready;
ajax1 = $.ajax({ url: '/1' });
ajax2 = $.ajax({ url: '/2' });
domready = $.Deferred();
$(domready.resolve);
init = $.when(domready, ajax1, ajax2);
```

http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Then you don't need to care about the code above any longer :

```
init.done(function () { alert('success'); });
init.fail(function () { alert('failure'); });
init.done(function ($, response1, response2) { 
    alert(response2[0]); // shows the data from the second Ajax call
});
```

Here is a live demo : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/s22dT/.

About your try, `jQuery.when()` returns a Promise object which has no `ready` method :

```
$.when().ready() // TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'ready'
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/